# Post Brexit Referendum employment theory

Tags: macroeconomics, theory, political-economy

According to Chuka Umunna, Labour MP for Streatham and prominent pro-EU campaigner:

> People were told: "if immigration levels fall, it will be easier to
>   get a job, and easier to get a job that's paid well." Since 2016, net
>   immigration from the EU has fallen. Yet this indicator has gotten
>   worse.

He did not cite which study the numbers came from, but let's just assume it's true. From a purely supply / demand perspective it does seem counter-intuitive, but it could be more nuanced and complicated than that.

My personal best guess was: this result could be from a lagged effect of all the previous immigration up until then. With the red tape and time needed to immigrate, settle down, get a sponsored visa, find a job, it may take months or years for immigration levels to have a measurable influence on jobs. I first envisioned conducting a lag / lead regression analysis to test my hypothesis, but have since redirected my interest in theory.

**Question:** Is there anything in existing economic theory that could explain a fall in immigration correlating and/or causing higher difficulty in finding employment? (note I use and/or for causality) And related, what other empirical findings outside the UK support Umunna's claim?

**Further Clarification:**

- "easier to get a job": I am not quite sure how to quantify this section of Umunna's claim, I'm guessing he meant: average number of months unemployed before finding a job, or perhaps he meant: average availability of jobs in said sector. In your answer, explain which interpretation you use.

Comment: There is **no** red tape needed to immigrate from the EU. There are **no** sponsored visas needed for EU citizens. So your own explanation collapses at the first reality check.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers For what it's worth,  I am neutral on Brexit. Also, I really am not an expert at this at all. I'm just curious more than anything as to the theory. I'm hoping someone can break it down for me.

Comment: No economist with integrity are able to produce such paper.  Because job is unlike product, it is never simple price matching.  Unless it is under `planned economy` , where people are force to  relocate and force to take up the job, then it is easy to "get a job", which you don't .have the rights to refuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anything in existing economic theory that could explain a
>   fall in immigration correlating and/or causing higher difficulty in
>   finding employment?

In addition to the lagged effect you outline, there are at least two possible causes for the paradox you describe. These *theoretical* possibilities are independent of which interpretation of unemployment is adopted. I'm unaware of (and not even searching for) statistical evidence of whether this actually occurs.

1. A reduction of immigration could also entail a reduction of demand of goods and services. If there's no demand, some businesses are likely to reduce their staff, leading to an oversupply of labor (i.e., unemployment).
2. High-skilled immigrants might boost the industry in a different country to an extent that renders that foreign economy more competitive than the domestic economy. A significant trend in that direction could prompt domestic companies to slash jobs or even to relocate to one such country where supply of high-skilled labor is stronger. That would lead to the unemployment of low-skilled workers in the domestic labor market.

As for 2., it is reasonable to say that --almost by definition-- the low-skilled workers outnumber high-skilled ones.